# How do I run setup and teardown code with each test in MSpec?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, mspec

I have generic code for setting up and tearing down NHibernate, which I need on pretty much all my tests. Is there a way to include the 'need for all tests' code in one place, then have it applied to all tests? (ie like Nunit's `setup` and `teardown` methods)

```
[Subject("Accessing the TAE allocation page")]
public class when_a_request_to_the_tae_allocation_page_is_made
{
    Establish context = () => NHTestHelper.StartTest(); //need for all tests

    Because of = () => result = new AllocationController(true).Index();

    It should_display_the_page = () => result.ShouldBeAView();

    Cleanup nh = () => NHTestHelper.EndTest(); //need for all tests

    static ActionResult result;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a class using the IAssemblyContext interface.  Your specification classes do not inherit from this.

```
 public class DataSpecificationBase : IAssemblyContext
    {
        public static Configuration configuration;

        void IAssemblyContext.OnAssemblyComplete()
        {

            NHibernateSession.CloseAllSessions();
            NHibernateSession.Reset();

        }

        void IAssemblyContext.OnAssemblyStart()
        {
            HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();

            string[] mappingAssemblies = RepositoryTestsHelper.GetMappingAssemblies();
            configuration = NHibernateSession.Init(new SimpleSessionStorage(),
                                                   mappingAssemblies,
                                                   new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate(),
                                                   "database.config");

            InitializeUserSession();            

            Console.WriteLine("OnAssemblyStart");
        }

        void InitializeUserSession()
        {
            ITWEntityRepo entityRepo = new TWEntityRepo();
            // TWEntity entity  = entityRepo.GetByUserName("1EB6472B-965B-41D5-8D77-3880D02FF518");
            TWEntity entity = entityRepo.GetByUserName("87BCA093-0B8C-4FDF-ABE8-1A843BA03608");

            UserSession.Instance().User = UserFactory.Create(entity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Alistair: this is not executed for _each_ test, but _once_ for all.

Comment: This answer is probably not what the OP wanted! AssemblyContext methods are executed ONCE for ALL tests, while NUnit's Setup and TearDown methods are executed ONCE for EACH test! MSpec does not have the concept you're looking for.